# Bluemix Single Sign On API with a Python application

Tags: python, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

Is there is a way to bind the Bluemix Single Sign On API with a Python application instead of Java Liberty and Nodejs ?

Answer (score 2):

As reported in the [Docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/index.html#sso_gettingstarted), currently the only two runtimes that are compatible with the SSO service are Liberty for Java and Node.js. However I've seen some Ruby applications using the SSO service in the past but I have no evidence of its integration with Python. You can take a look at [Bluemix with Python and Oauth2 (Single Sign On) for Authentication and Display of User Profile](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/167211/bluemix-with-python-and-oauth2-single-sign-on-for.html) as a starting point  but please note that as stated above only Liberty for Java and Node.js runtimes are fully supported.

Comment: I'm looking to secure my flask app with SSO.  It looks as though your answer is still the same 1 year on.